# How Sprite collision detection works?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to understand collision detection of two actors in libgdx.
This is what I am doing

```
Rectangle rect1 = sprite1.getBoundingRectangle();
Rectangle rect2 = sprite2.getBoundingRectangle();
if(rect1.overlaps(rect2))
 //collision occured
else
  //no collision
```

So far good but if you see code of getBoundingRectangle() in Actor class

```
    public Rectangle getBoundingRectangle () {
    final float[] vertices = getVertices();

    float minx = vertices[X1];
    float miny = vertices[Y1];
    float maxx = vertices[X1];
    float maxy = vertices[Y1];

    minx = minx > vertices[X2] ? vertices[X2] : minx;
    minx = minx > vertices[X3] ? vertices[X3] : minx;
    minx = minx > vertices[X4] ? vertices[X4] : minx;

    maxx = maxx < vertices[X2] ? vertices[X2] : maxx;
    maxx = maxx < vertices[X3] ? vertices[X3] : maxx;
    maxx = maxx < vertices[X4] ? vertices[X4] : maxx;

    miny = miny > vertices[Y2] ? vertices[Y2] : miny;
    miny = miny > vertices[Y3] ? vertices[Y3] : miny;
    miny = miny > vertices[Y4] ? vertices[Y4] : miny;

    maxy = maxy < vertices[Y2] ? vertices[Y2] : maxy;
    maxy = maxy < vertices[Y3] ? vertices[Y3] : maxy;
    maxy = maxy < vertices[Y4] ? vertices[Y4] : maxy;

    if (bounds == null) bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.x = minx;
    bounds.y = miny;
    bounds.width = maxx - minx;
    bounds.height = maxy - miny;
    return bounds;
}
```

It returns (minx, miny, x projection, y projection) of sprite, How can we determine collision from this information, IMO you need all the four coordinates to determine collision right? because in the above cases one rectangle facing +45° and -45° can have same above BoundingRectangle.

Summarizing the question, how is BoundingRectangle sufficient information for detecting collision, isn't some information lost?

Comment: Yes, for rotated sprites the bounding box is larger than the sprite, because this bounding box is always axis-aligned (the use of bounding boxes is always about high-speed approximation, and less of precision). Also note that for detecting collision it matters what is in the sprite, since the sprite is a rectangle itself, which always remains an approximation for non-rectangular objects (like a ball for example).

Comment: @tevemadar I have been struggling on trying to understanding this. I tried drawing Bounding rectangle of actor using

`shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
  shapeRenderer.setColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
  Rectangle bounds = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
  shapeRenderer.rect(bounds.getX(), bounds.getY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
  shapeRenderer.end();`

if actor is walking on x or y axis it is ok, but in any other direction bounding actor gets distorted, here is a https://youtu.be/KyzI72CWQR0 . is this expected? as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that is normal. If you can draw both the bounding box and the sprite, you may find it easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

*Sprite collision detection works by checking to see if the x and y values of two objects share a coordinate.*
If this occurs then you know the objects have collided. The `x` and `y` values of an object also include the values inside the shape.

However, there are several ways to check if they share an `x` and `y` coordinate without checking every possibility.

- For the `x` values you can check if the other shape is between the `x` position and `x` position + `width`.
- For the `y` values you can check if the other shape is between the `y` position and `y` position + `height`.

This changes based on the shape and number of sides.

Comment: I agree with your point, and it works perfectly if you are walking along axis, but if you go along a direction the height becomes projection on x and y, i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyzI72CWQR0, now you can see that this kind of comparison may  not work.